# Push patchset to gerrit own by another author

Tags: gerrit

I'm a gerrit user for few years now and I'm trying to setup a gerrit server in my new company. I succeed almost every configurations but I have two last issues (I'll discuss only one here).

I used to cherry-pick patchset that I didn't wrote (I'm not the author), change it to improve it (or rebase or whatever...), then push it to gerrit with the same change-id to become a patchset n + 1.

I currently have some trouble pushing the modify patchset.

Here what I have done.

1. Going to the patchset in gerrit I want to change
2. Cherry-pick this patchset into my local git repository
3. Update the source code
4. Commit the modification using the same change-id (since I really want to keep the all history and author ownership)
5. Trying to push to gerrit (git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/...)

The fifth point doesn't work. Here is the error:

```
$ git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/develop
  Counting objects: 16, done.
  Delta compression using up to 8 threads. 
  Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 2.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
  Total 16 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
  remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13)
  remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
  To ssh://gerrit.server.lan:29418/group/project
   ! [remote rejected]   HEAD -> refs/for/develop (cannot add patch set to 87.)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@gerrit.server.lan:29418/group/project'
```

Obviously user, server, group and project are correctly fill.
I'm using gerrit 2.13.5

I'm rebase over the gerrit/develop branch.

I guess I messed up some configurations but I cannot find which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is that you don't have "Add Patch Set" permission. See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_add_patch_set). This permission controls which users are allowed to upload new patch sets to existing changes.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly the configuration I missed

**addPatchSet = deny group Registered Users**

become **addPatchSet = group Registered Users**


Now everything is working as expected,

Thank you some much,

Cheers.